# Altium - Variation components wrongly displayed in 3d mode

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I'm currently working on a project in Altium 16.0 with three different variants of assembly. After selecting which components should not appear on each variant o schematic, I updated the PCB. Afterwards, on PCB mode, I went to the variants linstings and everything is according to the list made on schematic side.

My problem is, when I go into 3D mode, some components appear on the wrong variants, despite being correctly set to "not fitted" for that variant.

My question is, did anyone experience the same issue? If yes, how can I solve it?

Comment: I never found the schematic, PCB, or 3D model to update just by changing the variant selection. It only ever changes for me if you export something, using an OutJob for example. It doesn't seem to update in real-time. I expect if you set it to your other variation and export a STEP model of your board, it will be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the solution for this problem only now. If you go to Project -> Component Links and there are component not properlly linked between schematics and board, the 3D view will not sho these correctly. So on the refered window, if there are any components not linked, match them with the right arrow and perform update" on the bottom. Afterwards the 3D vire will show the correct models for each variant.